# Xcode TestFlight crash report is missing the important "Application Specific Backtrace"

Tags: xcode, testflight

I have a weird crash when running my own app after uploading and loading it from Testflight (though there's no crash when I run the app from Xcode directly).

The .ips file shows where the crash occured:

```
Application Specific Backtrace 0:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff81bc8b773 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff81b9ebbc3 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff81bbbcf16 -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 112
3   Find Any File                       0x000000010dd11b74 Find Any File + 637812
4   Find Any File                       0x000000010dce1106 Find Any File + 438534
5   AppKit                              0x00007ff81e6a2e7e -[NSClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 1125
6   UIFoundation                        0x00007ff81f535583 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 703
7   UIFoundation                        0x00007ff81f5352b7 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 253
8   AppKit                              0x00007ff81e61c977 -[NSNibConnector initWithCoder:] + 97
9   AppKit                              0x00007ff81e61c8b2 -[NSNibOutletConnector initWithCoder:] + 404
10  UIFoundation                        0x00007ff81f535583 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 703
11  UIFoundation                        0x00007ff81f5357a5 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1249
12  UIFoundation                        0x00007ff81f5352b7 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 253
13  AppKit                              0x00007ff81e61b698 -[NSIBObjectData initWithCoder:] + 170
14  UIFoundation                        0x00007ff81f535583 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 703
15  UIFoundation                        0x00007ff81f5352b7 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 253
16  AppKit                              0x00007ff81e6a1a92 -[NSNib _instantiateNibWithExternalNameTable:options:] + 526
17  AppKit                              0x00007ff81e6a178f -[NSNib _instantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 143
18  AppKit                              0x00007ff81ee2297f -[NSStoryboard _instantiateMainMenu:] + 189
19  AppKit                              0x00007ff81e60cbee NSApplicationMain + 712
20  dyld                                0x0000000117ab652e start + 462

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff81bb12ffe __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff81bb491ff pthread_kill + 263
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x7ff81ba94d24 abort + 123
3   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff81bb05082 abort_message + 241
4   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff81baf625d demangling_terminate_handler() + 266
5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x7ff81b9f2e11 _objc_terminate() + 96
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff81bb044a7 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
7   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff81bb06eeb __cxa_rethrow + 99
8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x7ff81b9fcd6c objc_exception_rethrow + 37
9   UIFoundation                        0x7ff81f535cb1 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 2541
10  UIFoundation                        0x7ff81f5352b7 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 253
11  AppKit                              0x7ff81e6a1a92 -[NSNib _instantiateNibWithExternalNameTable:options:] + 526
12  AppKit                              0x7ff81e6a178f -[NSNib _instantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 143
13  AppKit                              0x7ff81ee2297f -[NSStoryboard _instantiateMainMenu:] + 189
14  AppKit                              0x7ff81e60cbee NSApplicationMain + 712
15  dyld                                   0x117ab652e start + 462
```

As you can see, the "Backtrace 0" shows my app's (Find Any File) calls at lines 3 and 4, and I like to know where that is in my source code.

There's also the stack trace from the thread below it, but that's not helpful.

Now, when I view that same crash in Xcode's Organizer, I see this:

[image: Xcode Organizer showing the crashlog]

That shows the wrong stack trace, though! I.e. it shows the thread's stack trace that has no useful symbols for debugging this issue. I need instead to see the trace of the Backtrace 0 that contains my code's invocation of the `objectAtIndex:` message.

Similarly, when I then click the "Open in Project…" button, I end up with the same wrong stack view:

[image: Xcode debug view of wrong stack trace]

Why is Xcode getting this wrong? How do I work around this, so that I get the actual source code of "Find Any File + 637812", showing me the line that acccesses the out-of-bounds array index?

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract `0x000000010dd11b74` and `637812` and get the base address of FaF. Then you can open the binary in hopper, change the base address and see what’s located at `0x000000010dd11b74`.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't solve the basic issue of why crashreports sent from Apple from my account don't include the important stacktrace. So, if I rely on Apple to collect my crash reports, many of them may be useless like the one in my example. That seems to be a severe bug on Apple's end, unless I'm missing something and just "doing it wrong".